# PTE not being honored

Tags: kernel

I am trying to boot a custom fork of Apple’s XNU kernel ([sources](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel)). The kernel is written in a combination of assembler, C, and C++. I am currently *trying* to jump from the `_start` function, which is written in assembler due to the low-level operations it performs, into `vstart`, which is written in C.

I am getting a page fault on address `0x10BFF8`, which escalates into a triple-fault because the IDT has not yet been set up. Now, the thing is, I have 2048 PTD entries that map 2MB each; the zeroth stretches from the bottom of memory (address zero) to address `0x200000`, which includes `0x10BFF8`.

[Here are the page tables I’m using](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/boot_pt.c). Why isn’t the zeroth page table in the `BootPTD` array being honored? I am certain that it is *only* the zeroth page table that is being ignored. At the time of the triple fault, the register dump says that the instruction pointer points to address `0x2D15C0`, which is the address of `vstart`. This address falls into the range of the first PTD. If none of the PTDs are being honored, I would page-fault on that address instead.

(Please note, despite the array being named `BootPDT`, the `PS` bit is set in each entry, which tells the CPU that each entry maps 2MB of memory, instead of pointing to a PTE that maps 4K of memory.)

Comment: Whoa! A little background information would be helpful. Language, kernel, what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you are able to, I'd start by using a single 4k page with a assembly instruction to jump to some big numbered address with the intent of checking to see if any of your page tables are being loaded.